# how to create combination in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .csv file with layout like this

```
X1,Y1 
X2,Y1,Y2 
X3,Y1,Y2,Y3 
X4, 
X5,Y1
```

I am expecting an output like this

> X1,Y1
>   X2,Y1
>   X2,Y2
>   X3,Y1
>   X3,Y2
>   X3,Y3
>   X5,Y1

Is there anyway possible that I will get this kind of result?
or is there any possible way that is much easier to do this job?

yesterday, I am just able to read the CSV, I was browsing and got information about itertools permutation and combination(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/). I dont have itertools in my library and I do not know how to install it (i have tried all the way to do this).

import csv

with open ('list.csv') as csvfile:
    readCsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

```
datas = []

for row in readCsv:
    combi = row

    datas.append(combi)
```

Comment: There are probably several ways to do this. Which did you try? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would have been much nicer if you have posted your tries along with your question. Anyway, lets assume that you have already read your `.csv` file and your stored your data in this format:

```
data = [
    ['x1', 'y1'],
    ['x2', 'y1', 'y2'],
    ['x3', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3'],
    ['x4',],
    ['x5', 'y1'],
]
```

Then, your can iterate through each sub-list in your data and find all possible combinations. Straightforward solution:

```
res = []
for arr in data:
    comb = []
    for cell in arr[1:]:
        if len(arr) > 1:
            comb.append(arr[0] + ',' + cell)
    if comb:
        res.append(comb)
```

Also, you can replace `arr[0] + ',' + cell` with `join()`.
The output of the above would be:

```
[['x1,y1'], ['x2,y1', 'x2,y2'], ['x3,y1', 'x3,y2', 'x3,y3'], ['x5,y1']]
```

If you prefer one-line solution, then:

```
[[','.join((arr[0], cell)) for cell in arr[1:] if len(arr) > 1] for arr in data if len(arr) > 1]
```

The output would be the same.

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony for your help, it is a big help for a beginner like me